# iPhone, confusing memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with the bottom section of code. I was sure it was fine but "Leaks" says it is leaking, which quickly changing it to the top version stops, just not sure as to why?

```
// Leaks says this is OK
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"rotData-requested"]) {
    int myInt = [[self elementValue] intValue];
    NSNumber *valueAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt];
    [self setRotData:valueAsNumber];
    return;
}
```

.

```
// Leaks says this LEAKS    
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"rotData-requested"]) {
    NSNumber *valueAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self elementValue] intValue]];
    [self setRotData:valueAsNumber];
    return;
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

gary

Comment: At a glance, I can't see any issues with the code you have here.  How does `[self elementValue]` work and what does it return?

Comment: Certainly looks ok.  Sometimes Instruments lies - and iphoneos has enough leaks of it's own :-).

Comment: Very strange indeed. Does it still fail if you explicitly cast: `[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[[self elementValue] intValue]]`?

Comment: Does this leak appear on the device or just in the simulator? The simulator can sometimes report false leaks. If it doesn't show up on the device, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I am running on the simulator, the leak seems to point towards "numberWithInt:"

Comment: [self elementValue] is a @property(retain, nonatomic) NSString *elementValue;

Answer (score 1):

bug ， the memory leak check tools always produce bug